# Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1', located at

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I am trying to get a subreport working.  I am using VS 2010.  I've inserted a "Subreport1" into my main report and keep getting the error:  Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport1', located at....

Here's my code:

```
public partial class rptEngOrd : Form
{
    public rptEngOrd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<EngOrd> eoNumParam;
    private string eonum;
    private DataSet dsReport;
    private DataSet dsSubReport;

    private void rptEngOrd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadComboBoxes();
    }

    private void LoadComboBoxes()
    {
        try
        {
            eoNumParam = EngOrdDB.GetDistinctEONum();
            cboEONum.DataSource = eoNumParam;
            cboEONum.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (cboEONum.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("zALL"))
            {
                eonum = "";
            }
            else
            {
                eonum = cboEONum.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }

            //get the data
            dsReport = EngOrdDB.GetEngOrdbyEONum(eonum);

            //provide local report information to viewer
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CustomMenu.rptEngOrd.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

            //prepare report data source
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            rds.Name = "dsReport";
            rds.Value = dsReport.Tables[0];
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            //prepare sub report data source
            dsSubReport = EngOrdTaskDB.GetEngOrdTaskbyEONum(eonum);
            ReportDataSource rdsSub = new ReportDataSource();
            rdsSub.Name = "dsSubReport";
            rdsSub.Value = dsSubReport.Tables[0];
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsSub);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(srptProcessingEventHandler);

            //load the report viewer
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();


            //MessageBox.Show(eonum);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //display generic message back to user
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
        }

        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }

    private void srptProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDataSource r = reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[1];
        e.DataSources.Add(r);

    }       

}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a while a go this link that help me with the sub report data population, [Reporting against a domain model](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model/), you find the code that interests you about at the middle of the page.

By the way I think that you should populate and add the data only in the event handler

```
private void srptProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    dsSubReport = EngOrdTaskDB.GetEngOrdTaskbyEONum(eonum);
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource “dsSubReport”, dsSubReport.Tables[0]));
}
```

and you delete this code from the click event.

```
//prepare sub report data source
dsSubReport = EngOrdTaskDB.GetEngOrdTaskbyEONum(eonum);
ReportDataSource rdsSub = new ReportDataSource();
rdsSub.Name = "dsSubReport";
rdsSub.Value = dsSubReport.Tables[0];
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsSub);
```

In this way i should work. Hope this helps